# Are there any atheist or agnostic American astronauts, past or present?

Tags: nasa, astronauts, astronaut-lifestyle, astronaut-recruitment

Are there any atheist or agnostic American astronauts, past or present?

If no was this policy? (If no how did that happen and is there a policy going forward?)

Yes these are three questions but they so intertwined I opted to not make them three different questions.

Comment: I looked for the information but couldn’t find wether Jean Loup Chrétien was atheist or not. Would’ve been funny given his last name literally means Christian.

Comment: I hope there are, because a) atheists constitute a large fraction of the American population and b) atheists are by and large rational people with strong values who happen to reject religion because they find no factual basis to support its entertaining but outlandish claims. Not trying to stoke a fire. Just saying atheists exist, they have values, are good people, and they like cats and equal representation---just like religious people.

Answer (score 16):

> Are there any atheist or agnostic American astronauts, past or present?

With the hundreds of astronauts who have been through the American space program, I am sure there are more than a few atheists and agnostics, but they're likely quiet about it. The only publicly self-identified atheist astronaut I know of is not American, ESA's [Christer Fuglesang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christer_Fuglesang).

> If no was this policy? (If no how did that happen and is there a policy going forward?)

If there was a policy against atheist astronauts it would be rapidly and loudly challenged. The US constitution states "no religious Test shall ever be required as a Qualification to any Office or public Trust", and that clause has been interpreted fairly broadly by the courts. Organized atheist groups would be constantly protesting NASA if there was even a hint of a policy against hiring atheists as astronauts.

The early astronauts were pretty open about their religion, and at that time, being a church-going Christian of some denomination was a big part of the image that NASA was trying to cultivate for those astronauts -- while I'm sure there was no formal policy saying the astronauts selected for the Mercury program had to be Christian, open atheists simply wouldn't have been selected at that time. On the flip side, it's impossible to know how many of these churchgoing nominal Christians actually were believers. It was very common in the 20th century US for atheists or agnostics to attend church to fit in with their communities.

Some of the Apollo astronauts seem to have had their religious beliefs strengthened by their experience, while others did not.

Apollo 15's [James Irwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Irwin#Personal_life) was a lapsed Christian but became a devout [born-again Christian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_again) after his flight.

A16's [Charlie Duke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Duke) also became born-again in 1978 but it's not clear from his WP article what his religious practice was during Apollo.

Duke's A16 crewmate [John Young was unmoved](https://medium.com/@room_n/john-young-the-astronaut-fe2c1076a986):

> Interviewer: Did you discover God up there?
>
> Young: No. I don’t think so.
>
> Interviewer: No sense of awe? Wonder?
>
> Young: No.
>
> Interviewer: Why not?
>
> Young: Because I think that the way things are in space are the way they are and I think that’s a good thing. I think that if people have to go into space to discover God, they have some other kind of problem.

This sounds like Young was an agnostic, but it's not necessarily conclusive.

A14's [Ed Mitchell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_Mitchell) held [unconventional spiritual beliefs](https://www.hinduismtoday.com/modules/smartsection/item.php?itemid=1059).

In the shuttle and post-shuttle era, there was a significant shift in astronaut demographics: scientists and engineers constituted significant portions of the astronaut corps, which was previously dominated by military officers with test pilot training. Of the 12 Apollo moon walkers, for example, only one, A17 LMP [Harrison Schmitt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrison_Schmitt), was a scientist; on the later shuttle missions it was common for 3-5 members of a 7-person crew to be engineers or scientists. Atheists and agnostics make up a larger proportion of the scientific community than the military, so one would expect more of them in the 21st century astronaut corps.

Over the last several decades, a couple of things happened: astronauts became less celebrated, and American attitudes toward organized religion shifted. Since the public doesn't see as much of an astronaut's private life as they did in the 1960s, it's easier for an astronaut to keep their beliefs -- religious or not -- private. Fewer Americans are involved in organized religion today, and to avoid conflicts, many Americans avoid raising the topic of religion, especially in the workplace, and doubly so in government workplaces.

Comment: Another pressure to depict early astronauts as church-going Christians was to portray them as the opposite to Soviet cosmonauts.  The space race was happening and many Americans felt that their religiousness made them superior to "God-fearing communists".

Comment: That would be "Godless communists"...

Comment: Have any atheists been to the moon? 

And as you say NASA had been cultivating the 'doing god's work' policy. Did that shift occur with the liberalization of the late 60's?

As for Article VI, is it true it applies only to elected or oath-taking positions?

Comment: The [WP article on the "no religious test" clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Religious_Test_Clause) indicates that applies to any federal government position, not just elected or sworn positions, but I'm not an expert on the judicial history there. I'll incorporate some info I found about the religious beliefs of some of the Apollo astronauts.

Comment: I'm not sure Young's statement is atheist, I'd say it suggested the opposite, however it might have been a carefully crafted response to have that effect.

Comment: @JCRM Hmm yeah I see how it could be read either way.

Comment: re: Article IV ... "By its plain terms, no federal officeholder or employee can be required to adhere to or accept any particular religion or doctrine as a prerequisite to holding a federal office or a federal government job."

Got it.

Comment: "The most prominent cosmonaut atheist was Gherman Titov, whose flight in August 1961 followed Yuri Gagarin’s that April. In 1962, he told an audience at the Seattle world’s fair that he had seen no gods or angels in space, and that he believed in mankind’s strength and reason. This poster – titled There Is No God! –commemorates him."  https://www.theguardian.com/artanddesign/gallery/2019/oct/23/down-with-god-how-the-soviet-union-took-on-religion-in-pictures#img-4

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune Claims of atheism by Soviet astronauts should be treated with some skepticism.  While there was (and, to a lesser extent, still is) some benefit in the US for an atheist to keep quiet about it, there was, to a much greater extent, pressure in the Soviet Union to do the opposite, to hide your religion.  Religion was brutally repressed by the Soviets.

Comment: I'd also note that "no gods or angels in space" is probably equally consistent with atheism and various religions (including most forms of Christianity and probably most common forms of monotheism) that adhere to doctrines that God or angels shouldn't be seen in space anymore than on the surface of the earth.

Answer (score 3):

William Anders who flew on Apollo 8 started to question his Catholic beliefs on his flight. He became an atheist.

The Seattle Times' December 24, 2018 piece [With a view from beyond the moon, an astronaut talks religion, politics and possibilities](https://www.seattletimes.com/pacific-nw-magazine/with-a-view-from-beyond-the-moon-an-astronaut-talks-religion-politics-and-possibilities/) alludes to this:

> Ironically, Anders’ six days in space forever altered his own view of his place in the universe. Raised a Catholic, Anders says he held generally to a traditional Christian viewpoint of the Earth being created by a God who fashioned Earthlings in his own image.
>
> The view from space changed everything.
>
> Earth, seen from the moon, Anders explains, looks to be about the size of your fist at arm’s length. Two lunar distances away, it’s half that size; at eight, it’s one-eighth of that. And so on. Even at 100 lunar distances, still far short of Mars or any other planet, Earth is rendered as a dust speck — beyond insignificant against the vast scale of the universe.
>
> It is one thing to imagine this. It’s another to get far enough into space to feel it.
>
> “When I looked back and saw that tiny Earth, it snapped my world view,” Anders says. “Here we are, on kind of a physically inconsequential planet, going around a not particularly significant star, going around a galaxy of billions of stars that’s not a particularly significant galaxy — in a universe where there’s billions and billions of galaxies.”
>
> “Are we really that special? I don’t think so.”

Comment: This answer would be improved by citing a source.

Comment: To my best knowledge, practically no Catholic would have any problem with the space exploration, and they do not consider it contradicting with the Bible in any sense. Some neo-protestant branches of the Christianity does, but they are a minority even in the USA. Flat Earth theory and similars do not root in religions, they root in the low quality of the elementary education in the USA.

Comment: The Catholic church not only "has no problem" with space exploration, it actively supports it!  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatican_Observatory

Comment: I've added a block quote from your source [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/51986/12102). That was probably meant to be a comment and should be incorporated into this answer rather than a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have only casually spoken with a few (maybe six) former astronauts while I was visiting the Kennedy Space Center at Cape Canaveral.  From my conversations with those former travelers into space, with me  inquiring about any self proclaimed atheists of those who have been in space, the former astronauts say that they are knowledgeable of none.

Comment: I edited your question and removed your personal narrative. Stack Exchange answers need to be based on facts. Occasionally information which can't be verified *can be added to a question that contains verifiable information as well*. Can you add anything to this that can be independently verified? Thanks! and *Welcome to Space!*

Comment: @uhoh  Whose question.

Comment: I can not remember a single sentence in the Bible saying that God would be some super-developed material thing in the sky/space. It is a possible interpretation for people not knowing science. Btw, the science-related content of the Bible is practically zero. The little about stars/sky/space are about how do the ancient people perceived the reality, while it does not say anything about the reality itself, and it is never in the focal point of the context.

Answer (score 1):

Without a doubt, Rusty Schweickart was an atheist during his selection. He even told a fellow astronaut and asked what he should say when asked about his faith. He said, “No religious preference” as did Anders and one other out of the 14 in their first press conference.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I would have less "doubt" if you have a source for this "He even told a fellow astronaut and asked what he should say when asked about his faith"